# Get additional column values from selected item in list view using Javascript\JQuery

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

I'm currently using JS (items[i].id;) to successfully get the id of selected items in a list view, however, I would like to pull column values from the selected row(s) like "Title" etc. if possible using JS\JQuery. Is there a method for doing this by traversing the DOM instead of using the GetItemById method?  Thanks!

Here is the code I'm using...

```
function WriteSelected() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    var i;

    for (i in items)
        {
            //alert (items[i].id);
        }       
}
```

Comment: Please share the code snippet that you are using currently to get the item ID.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use Fields **not** displayed in the View ??

Comment: No sir. The values I want are already columns in the view. My end goal is to take those values and write them to another list.

Answer (score 1):

There is an object exposed by Sharepoint that you can use which is called WPQ2ListData which contains the current information of the list/grid.

Here's an example snippet to achieve what you need:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
items.forEach(function(item){
   console.log('Id selected: ' + item.id);
   var listItem = WPQ2ListData.Row.filter(function(row){
        return row.ID == item.id;
    })[0];
 console.log('List Item:');
 console.log(listItem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to use the DOM instead of the ctx object...

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("tr[class~='s4-itm-selected']")
                ,function(tr){
                               console.log(tr.getAttribute('iid').split(',')[1])
                             }
               );
```

Gets you the Item ID of all selected TRs

Comment: Honestly, I don't need the id's of the selected items unless I need to get the value of the columns from the GetItemById method. I just want to get the field values as efficiently as possible and run..

Comment: Then do ``a .map`` to get the selected IDs and then a ``ctx.ListData.Row.filter()`` ?